# How to check minimum code coverage for multi-module maven project with jacoco?

Tags: maven, testing, code-coverage, jacoco-maven-plugin

I want to use `jacoco maven plugin` for checking minimum level of code coverage during build process using `'check'` goal.

For one-module project everything works fine.
But for multi-module I want to check average level of code coverage from all modules, but `check` goal checks every module separately.

For example, **module1** has **70%** of code coverage, **module2** has **100%** code coverage, in average for all lines from both modules code coverage is **85%**.
And I am trying to set code coverage for all project to 80%, but it fails because of first module.

From pom:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.6.201602180812</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>default-report</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>default-check</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <rules>
                    <rule>
                        <element>BUNDLE</element>
                        <limits>
                            <limit>
                                <counter>COMPLEXITY</counter>
                                <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                <minimum>0.80</minimum>
                            </limit>
                        </limits>
                    </rule>
                </rules>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: not possible (at the time of writing) using merely Maven and Jacoco.

from [official jacoco github page](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/wiki/MavenMultiModule):

> The current JaCoCo Maven goals work on single modules only: Tests are executed within the module and contribute coverage only to code within the same module. Coverage reports are created for each module separately. There is no built-in support for cross-module coverage or combined reports for multiple modules.

Hence your requirements cannot be met merely using Maven and Jacoco. You can however use a common approach in enterprise settings: Sonarqube, which will process the generated jacoco files (i.e. `jacoco.exec`) and aggregate reporting and governance via its Jacoco integration (provided out-of-the-box on its latest versions).

Comment: Thanks, I implemented such approach via Jacoco plugin for Jenkins

Comment: Hello, is there any update to this answer in 2019? I am able to use `report-aggregate` to generate a nice html report with aggregates. If that's possible, then jacoco should be able to generate an aggregate `jacoco.exec`, and then I should be able to check the aggregate coverage, no?

Comment: @user770119 - This is still not supported as discussed in https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jacoco/0haFMvGBng0/A4UfH_sjBgAJ

Comment: It's 2021.  Does anyone have any news? *hopeful*

Answer (score 0):

Source: https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/check-mojo.html

Use Bundle with counter Intruction, this will check overall code coverage for the whole project:

```
<rules>
<rule>
    <element>BUNDLE</element>
    <limits>
        <limit>
            <counter>INSTRUCTION</counter>
            <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
            <minimum>0.80</minimum>
        </limit>
    </limits>
</rule>
```